# creating a basic baseball game using a surface view i am trying to get my baseball image to show

Tags: android, surfaceview

i am trying to create a basic baseball game in android. The background image is set to a xml file, and i want to set a base ball image on home plate to be moved on touch of the screen. Th problem is that i cannot get the baseball image to show. The app itself has 5 activities and the game is one activity inside the app. I am new to android and developing a basic game. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
`
To start this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.Stats"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.STATS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.DrinkingBaseballGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.DRINKINGBASEBALLGAME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.MyGameSurface"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.ShowStatistics"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myapp.ron.drinkingbaseball.SHOWSTATISTICS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my main game java code

```
public class DrinkingBaseballGame extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    MyGameSurface mySurface;
    float x, y, sx, sy, fx, fy, dx, dy, anix, aniy, scaledX, scaledY;
    Bitmap ball, background;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mySurface = new MyGameSurface(this);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        sx = 0;
        sy = 0;
        fx = 0;
        fy = 0;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
        anix = 0;
        aniy = 0;
        scaledX = 0;
        scaledY = 0;
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.baseball);
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.baseball_field_background);
        setContentView(R.layout.drinkingbaseball);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mySurface.pause();
    }

    @Override`enter code here`
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mySurface.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            sx = event.getX();
            sy = event.getY();
            dx = dy = anix = aniy = scaledX = scaledY = fx = fy = 0;    
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            fx = event.getX();
            fy = event.getY();
            dx = fx - sx;
            dy = fy - sy;
            scaledX = dx/30;
            scaledY = dy/30;
            x = y = 0;
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }   

    public class MyGameSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

        SurfaceHolder myHolder;
        Thread myThread = null;
        boolean isRunning = false;

        public MyGameSurface(Context context) {
            super(context);
            myHolder = getHolder();
        }

        public void pause(){
            isRunning = false;
            while(true){
                try{
                    myThread.join();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            myThread = null;
        }

        public void resume(){
            isRunning = true;
            myThread = new Thread(this);
            myThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(isRunning){
                if(!myHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

                Canvas canvas = myHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawBitmap(ball, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/4, null);

                myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my surface code

```
public class MyGameSurface extends View{

    Bitmap background, ball;
    float changingY;

    public MyGameSurface(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.baseball);
        changingY = 0;
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.baseball_field_background);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);       
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, canvas.getWidth()/4, changingY, null);
        if(changingY < canvas.getHeight()){
            changingY += 10;
        }else{
            changingY = 0;
        }
        invalidate();   
    }

}
`
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Statement: "Th problem is that i cannot get the baseball to show." is not providing enough info for anyone to help you :)

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Have you tried creating an `ImageView` setting the image to your baseball image and then try calling `bringToFront()` on the `ImageView` to make sure it is above (z-axis) the `SurfaceView`. Again, you need to provide more information so we can more accurately help you

Comment: I added my code so far

Comment: i am trying to add the baseball image on top of a baseball field background image i have in another xml file. I am not sure if i am doing this right or not.

Comment: Why do you have two classes called MyGameSurface? You are basically having very wrong concept for this. I suggest going back to the drawing board before you get any deeper in this.

Comment: The reason i had two is because like i said i am new to designing a game in android and i had thought originally that just using a view might work but after doing some research on it i realized that using a surface view made more sense so i added that class to see if i was possibly on the right track with that one

Comment: Did you tried the answer?

Comment: yes i did thank you that worked thank you very much. Just so i know by original concept you meant having more then one MyGameSurface

Comment: You are welcome. If you are going to make a game with surface view you have to look at some tutorials on how to do that. And all of those use just one surface view. This is totally off this topic. Try googles lunar landing example to see how they do it. :)

Comment: ok thanks again Marko I appreciate it and i will lookup the example you suggested and if i have any more issues i will ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this code of yours to work just replace this line with

```
setContentView(R.layout.drinkingbaseball);
```

with this one

```
setContentView(mySurface);
```

But I still stand behind my words that your concept is not good.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: setting the content view to my surface did work but i went about it differently. I used lunar lander example which did work well Thanks again Marko